# install4j: How can I use alternate jvm for the launchers

Tags: java, install4j, openj9

We are trying to use alternative jvms, this is from 
    https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/

when starting our launcher with /create-i4j-log we got:

```
[1:16] Trying to load JVM-DLL from c:\qomet2\jre\bin\javaw.exe
[1:18] Setting PATH ...
[1:19] Trying c:\qomet2\jre\bin\hotspot\jvm.dll (exists 0)
[1:20] Trying c:\qomet2\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll (exists 0)
[1:21] Trying c:\qomet2\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll (exists 0)
[1:22] Trying c:\qomet2\jre\bin\classic\jvm.dll (exists 0)
[1:23] Trying c:\qomet2\jre\bin\jrockit\jvm.dll (exists 0)
```

I think the problem is, the jvm.dll is located in
    jdk8u192-b12\jre\bin\j9vm\jvm.dll

Then launcher says, "invalid jvm installation" and quits.

So how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

As of 7.x this is not supported in the GUI, but you can edit the project file, look for the "preferredVM" attribute on the "java" element and set it to "j9vm".

install4j 8.x will automatically search for this VM.

Comment: Hi Ingo, when is 8.x with OpenJ9 support planned for release?

Comment: Actually, this will be in 7.0.10 later this week or early next week.